# Swift timer not following correct interval

Tags: swift, nstimer, ios13

I am trying to create a quiz app which has a timer for each question when the timer expires (i.e. 10 seconds and I want `Timmer` to have an interval of 1 sec) it resets it self and next question is fetched and `Timmer` again restart from 10... But my issue is the timer doesn't follow a fixed interval when first question is loaded it shows interval of 2 ... i.e. 10,8,6 .. and then for second question it makes jump for 3 secs interval and similarly the interval increases.

```
var countTime = 10.0
func handleNextQuestion() throws {
            nextQuestion()
            if questionCounter == allQuestions.list.count-1{
                finishButton.isHidden = false
                nextButton.isHidden = true
                //scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"
            }
        }
        
        func nextQuestion(){
            showResultView(isCorrect: (question?.isAnswerCorrect)!)
            questionCounter = questionCounter + 1
            question = fetchQuestion()
            setQuizView(question: question!)
            
            
        }
        
        @objc func update() {
            if(countTime > 0) {
                countTime = countTime - 1
                self.countDownLabel.text = String(countTime)
            }else{
                timer.invalidate()
                countTime = 10.0
                do{
    
                    try handleNextQuestion()
    
                }
                catch{
                       moveToResultView()
                }
                
            }
        }
     
        
       
        func startTimer() {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        func setQuizView(question:Question)  {
            self.countDownLabel.text = "10"
          startTimer()
            startTimer()
            questionLabel.text =  question.questionText
            ansLbl1.text =  question.answer1
            ansLbl2.text =  question.answer2
            ansLbl3.text =  question.answer3
            ansLbl4.text =  question.answer4
            
            if question.selectedAnswer == Constants.DEFAULT_ANSWER {
                for checkBoxItem in checkBoxlist{
                    checkBoxItem.isChecked = false
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: You are calling startTimer() twice in setQuizView

Comment: sorry for that I modified the code while copy pasting removed some part of the code so it happened to add extra startTimer() which wasnt part of the original code . but its still having issue..edited question

Comment: thanks @Yunnosch You are right about it pardon me for my mistake..creating a new one

Comment: Everybody is learning. You are doing well. Have fun.

Comment: It's not part of your code but how is the timer object declared, it looks somehow like you have multiple timers going? And now you are calling startTimer() twice again. Please double check your post before saving.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have already explained above that it was by mistake while copying the code.. to stackoverflow

Comment: @Yunnosch have created new question hope it helps. thanks for correcting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154785/swift-nstiimer-not-following-specified-interval

Comment: But now it is back again with one of your latest edits

Answer (score 0):

`func setQuizView(question:Question)`

calls `startTimer()` twice. I think that explains the behaviour. On each new question the timer is started twice but only invalidated once so the seconds jump by an extra one exach question.

just delete one of the calls to `startTimer()`